# Why is the metric distance defined as maximum of the set of metric distances on the finite product of metric spaces?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

[image: metric space example]

Why is the metric distance defined as maximum of the set of metric distances on the finite product of metric spaces ?

I think the triangular inequality will not be satisfied but l cannot understand the bigger picture. Will appreciate a good example.

Comment: This is just one of the useful metrics on the product. Nothing very special about this metric.

Comment: @Kavi So we can also define metric distance as minimum ?

Comment: No, the minimum  wont be a metric. But you can use the sum or square root of the sum of squares. etc.

Comment: @Kavi It probably sounds stupid but which one of the four properties will fail if l use minimum distance as a metric ?

Comment: If the distance between two points in the product is $0$ for (the minimum) we cannot say that the two points coincide. We can only say that one of the coordinates coindides.

Comment: @Kavi Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Kavi Rama Murthy said, in terms of topology, the $max$-metric is only one of many choices that induce the same topology. Other typical choices include

$$d_{A \times B}((x,y),(x',y')) := d_A(x,x') + d_B(y,y')$$

and

$$d_{A \times B}((x,y),(x',y')) := \sqrt{d_A(x,x')^2 + d_B(y,y')^2}$$

(At least) if the metric is induced by a norm, then

$$d_{A \times B}((x,y),(x',y')) := (d_A(x,x')^p + d_B(y,y')^p)^{1/p}$$

for $p \in [1, \infty)$ is another choice. However, the $\max$-metric has a universal property:

Consider the category where objects are metric spaces and morphisms are non-expansive maps i.e. maps $f: A \rightarrow B$ such that $d_B(f(x),f(y)) \leq d_A(x,y)$. Let $(A,d_A)$ and $(B,d_B)$ be two metric spaces in this category, then $(A \times B, d_{A \times B})$ with $d_{A \times B} ((x,y), (x',y')):= \max\{d_A(x,x'), d_B(y,y')\}$ is the categorical product of the two spaces.

Essentially, this comes down to checking the definition and the fact that $\max\{d_A(x,x'), d_B(y,y')\}$ being the least upper bound of the two values. That is, if for some other space $(Z,d_Z)$ there exists a maps $f_A: Z \rightarrow A$, $f_B: Z \rightarrow B$ with $\forall z,z' \in Z: d_A(f_A(z),f_A(z')) \leq d_Z(z,z')$ and $d_B(f_B(z),f_B(z')) \leq d_Z(z,z')$, then $d_Z(z,z')$ also dominates their supremum, which is the metric on $A \times B$.